I'm trying to add a class here in Tailwind CSS:
enter image description here
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="text-2xl text-green-500">Netflix Clone</h1>
    </>
  );

This is my tailwind.config.js

    /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
    module.exports = {
      content: ["./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
      content: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
      content: ["./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
      theme: {
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [],
    }


I'm using react, nextjs and tailwind.
But it's not rendering; I've already installed the dependencies correctly. Actually, the Tailwind styling worked, only this class isn't working. In the code along I'm following, the instructor did it and it worked, but I don't understand why it's not working here. If anyone can shed some light on this, I'd appreciate it.

Update your question to include tailwind.config.js and the path of this file

what is the file path? where is it in your project?

Did you try to put them inside the one content ? Like content: ['/path/to/components','/path/to/pages','/path/to/app']

@xenooooo i do not, but now i dont know what happnd, part of is working now

Using the same key content multiple times overwrites the value - only the last value would be kept.

content: ["./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],

This tells apply styles inside all directories inside ./app (app in root) for files with 'js,ts,jsx,tsx' extensions. And if you want multiple locations you can do like this,
content: ["./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],


You can achieve this by extending the theme object in your tailwind.config.js file.
module.exports = {
  content: ....,
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        customGreen: "#00FF00", // Define your custom color here
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};

and then can use this below
<h1 className="text-2xl text-customGreen">Netflix Clone</h1>

wish this is helpful.

I did what you put in the code and removed the error (don't know how), but now I added another class body {
at apply bg-zinc-900 h-full overflow-x-hidden;
}
It wasn't working because of the at apply, but now it is... I don't know what it could be, but the color green didn't work, even when adding custom as you said, thanks in advance but do you have any idea what it could be?"
